# How to avoid dividing by zero in SQL query?

Tags: sql

In my websites authors can upload their books.
I display statistics on each page and one of the stats I display is the average rating of the author's books. 
I take the sum of all the ratings, and divide it by the number of books:

```
select 
    sum(BookRate)/count(BookID) as AvrageRate 
from Books 
where Author = "Some Author"
```

The problems appear when the user has not yet uploaded any books and an obvious error message is returned:

```
Divide by zero error encountered.
```

Is there a way to avoid this situation within the SQL query or do I have to first check the book count with one query, and then run another query for the stats?

Thanks world.

Comment: That can't happen with the actual query in your question. If no books are uploaded and the `where` clause returns no rows the `SUM(BookRate)` will be `NULL` and that trumps the divide by zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `CASE` to cater for the sum of zero:

```
select case sum (BookID) 
    when 0 then 0
    else sum (BookRate)/sum (BookID) 
end as AvrageRate 
from Books where Author="Some Author"
```

BTW, don't you want to divide by the count, rather than sum to get the average?:

```
select case count(BookID) 
    when 0 then 0
    else sum (BookRate)/count(BookID) 
end as AvrageRate 
from Books where Author="Some Author"
```

Comment: Dividing by the count.. it was a typo. but yeah, it would make more sense :)

Comment: All answers work. you were the first. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use NULLIF() if you are using Oracle

```
NULLIF( 0, 0 )
```

In SQL Server also you can try this:

```
Select dividend / nullif(divisor, 0)
```

So in your case it could be like this:

```
select sum (BookRate)/nullif(sum (BookID),0) as AvrageRate 
from Books where Author="Some Author"
```

Comment: You can use this as well if you are using MS SQL

Answer (score 3):

If the user has not uploaded any books, then I'm not convinced that you will get a divide-by-zero error.  Instead, no rows will be returned.

In any case, the safest way is to use the `case` statement:

```
select (case when sum(BookId) > 0 then sum(BookRate)/count(BookID) end) as AvrageRate
from Books
where Author="Some Author";
```

Or, for this particular case, to use the `avg()` aggregation function:

```
select avg(BookRate) as AvrageRate
from Books
where Author="Some Author";
```

Comment: is using the avg function more efficient?

Comment: @MichaelSeltenreich . . . It is much clearer in intent, if that is what you want to do.  As for efficiency, it should be about the same.